# Extract values of pixels from each band of a multi-band raster with a shapefile in Python

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, point

I have downloaded multiple products from EO-1 satellite and I have created digital rasters out of them. Each of them contains 10 or 242 bands (those are hyperspectral). I have also created a shapefile for each of them with multiple points. Now I would like to create a table/array with Python containing values of a pixel from each band with coordinates from a shapefile. I would like to have all bands in separate columns and all points in separate rows.
I have managed to create such data frame in R, and I tried to do so with GDAL and numpy but I am far less familiar with Python.

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. Can you provide your efforts (*i.e* a code sample of what you have tried using Python)? Furthermore, check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/323272/86131) I wrote sometime ago. It might be a good starting point for retrieving pixel values from xy coordinates.

Comment: I think, it has already been answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221292/retrieve-pixel-value-with-geographic-coordinate-as-input-with-gdal?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46893/getting-pixel-value-of-gdal-raster-under-ogr-point-without-numpy).