# Reading raster values in points gives back a generator object instead of actual value

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, extract, values

Given a raster TIF file and a point feature class in a geodatabase, I am trying to extract the values of the raster on the points and add them as a new column on the point feature class. I am using the following piece of code:

```
import ....
gdb_path = r'.......gdb'
pnts = gpd.read_file(gdb_path, driver='FileGDB', layer='...')
raster_path = r'.........tif'

#building list of pairs of coordinates
temp = [pnts['geometry'].x, pnts['geometry'].y]
coords = list(map(list, zip(*temp)))

with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
    pnts['values'] = src.sample(coords)
```

The code above creates a new column on the points feature class where the value for each point is a `generator object sample_gen at 0x000.....` instead of the actual raster value.

I could loop point by point instead, like this:

```
raster = rasterio.open(raster_path)
for id, row in pnts.iterrows():
    for val in raster.sample([(row['geometry'].x, row['geometry'].y)]):
        pnts.at[id, 'value'] = val[0]
```

This seems to work ok, but it takes a really long time (I have 4 millions of points). So, this solution is not valid for my purposes.

Could anyone shed some light on how can I make the first piece of code produce what I need? Or any other approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The samples are lazily evaluated and returned as a generator so it can scale - i.e you can sample large numbers of points from a massive raster without having to load the raster, all the points and sampled values in memory.

Each element the generator returns is a list of values, one for each band in your raster. This is true even if there's only one band and thus a single sampled value for each point.

So you can't just use `pnts['values'] = 
 list(src.sample(coords))` otherwise for a single band raster you end up with something like:

```
print(pnts['values'])
0       [0.5706134]
1      [0.39265066]
2       [0.7231091]
3       [0.8030734]
4       [0.4549229]
           ...
```

So you need to grab the first element if you have a single band raster, something like:

```
with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
    pnts['values'] = [sample[0] for sample in src.sample(coords)]

print(pnts['values'])
0      0.570613
1      0.392651
2      0.723109
3      0.803073
4      0.454923
         ...
```

Comment: This seems to work really well (fast enough). And thanks for the clarification about the generator.

Answer (score 1):

I [answered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/323272/86131) a somewhat similar question a while ago and I think it can be adapted for your example. Hopefully it runs faster than your actual solution. Also, I haven't worked with `rasterio` but as it is build on top of `gdal`, I assume you can just use `gdal` as well.

Here is a function that will get the indices for the points (coordinates) you want (note that the spatial reference of both the points and the raster should be the same):

```py
import numpy


def get_indices(x, y, ox, oy, pw, ph):
    """
    Gets the row (i) and column (j) indices in an array for a given set of coordinates.
    Based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/92015/86131

    :param x:   array of x coordinates (longitude)
    :param y:   array of y coordinates (latitude)
    :param ox:  raster x origin
    :param oy:  raster y origin
    :param pw:  raster pixel width
    :param ph:  raster pixel height
    :return:    row (i) and column (j) indices
    """

    i = np.floor((oy-y) / ph).astype('int')
    j = np.floor((x-ox) / pw).astype('int')

    return i, j
```

Having this, you can open the raster, get its origin and dimensions and then pass them along with the point's x and y coordinates to the function:

```py
import gdal

ds = gdal.Open(raster_path, 0)
xmin, xres, xskew, ymax, yskew, yres = ds.GetGeoTransform()

idx = get_indices(pnts['geometry'].x.values, pnts['geometry'].y.values, xmin, ymax, xres, -yres)
```

Finally, you just have to read the raster as a `numpy` array and index it to get the values. Note that the raster should have only a single band or you should just read one of the bands. Otherwise, you would need to get the indices for the third dimension as well.

```py
arr = ds.ReadAsArray()
pnts['values'] = arr[idx]
del ds
```

Comment: "*I haven't worked with `rasterio`*" - give it a try, you won't regret it :)

Comment: @user2856 Definitely will!

Comment: Thx Marcelo for your answer. I believe your suggestion would also require looping point by point, correct? (which is what I am trying to avoid, because I think that's what makes it so slow)

Comment: This leverages numpy vectorization so you are not really doing normal Python `for` loops. You can compare this to the other answer and your current solution and see which one runs faster.